# MockBean annotation in Spring Boot test causes NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mockito

I am having trouble using the @MockBean annotation. The docs say MockBean can replace a bean within the context, but I am getting a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException within my unit test. I can't see how to use the annotation. If I can mock the repo, then obviously there will be more than one bean definition.

I am following the examples found here: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

I have a mongo repository:

```
public interface MyMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDTO, String>
{
   MyDTO findById(String id);
}
```

And a Jersey resource:

```
@Component
@Path("/createMatch")
public class Create
{
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Autowired
    private MyMongoRepository repository;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createMatch(@Context HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        MyDTO match = new MyDTO();
        match = repository.save(match);
        URI matchUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(String.format("/%s/details", match.getId())).build();

        return Response.created(matchUri)
                .entity(new MyResponseEntity(Response.Status.CREATED, match, "Match created: " + matchUri))
                .build();
    }
}
```

And a JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestMocks {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private MyMongoRepository mockRepo;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        given(this.mockRepo.findById("1234")).willReturn(
                new MyDTO());
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/1234/details", MyResponseEntity.class);

    }

}
```

Error message:

```
Field repository in path.to.my.resources.Create required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - myMongoRepository: defined in null
    - path.to.my.MyMongoRepository#0: defined by method 'createMock' in null
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6541

The fix is in spring-data `1.0.2-SNAPSHOT` and `2.0.3-SNAPSHOT` : https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/14#issuecomment-374141173

If you aren't using these version, you can work around it by declaring the mock with its name:

```
@MockBean(name="myMongoRepository")
private MyMongoRepository repository;
```

---

**In response to your comment**

From [Spring's doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html):

> For convenience, tests that need to make REST calls to the started
>   server can additionally @Autowire a TestRestTemplate which will
>   resolve relative links to the running server.

Reading this, I think you need to declare `@SpringBootTest` with a web environment:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

If your spring boot doesn't start the web environment, then what is the need for `TestRestTemplate`. Thus, I guess spring does not even make it available.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and now Spring can't autowire TestRestTemplate: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'path.to.my.tests.TestMocks': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate': No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: Ah yeah, I had removed the webenvironment thing and forgot. I re-added it, and now I'm getting an error about no suitable HttpMessageConverter for my DTO class. So it looks like I'm past the original error and on to learning about HttpMessageConverters. Thanks!

Comment: Which spring-boot version are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "issue" in `spring-boot 2.3.9` but it's not a bug, it's problem with the configuration of beans.

At least, There are two ways to solve it:

**Set `name` parameter in @MockBean annotation:**

In the test, add a `name` to `MockBean`:

```
@MockBean(name="myRepository")
private MyRepository diffrentName;
```

and in the production codebase use `myRepository` as filed name :

```
@Autowired
private MyRepository myRepository;
```

The name of @MockBean must be the same as the name of the field.

**Name a MockBean filed the same as a dependency in code.**

In the test, use the correct name of MockBean filed:

```
@MockBean
private MyRepository customRepository;
```

and in the production codebase use `customRepository` as filed name :

```
@Autowired
private MyRepository customRepository;
```

in that way, You indicate which bean You want to use.

I hope this will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! However, if I have the same name in both prod and test and the name was same as the type it didn't work. So if I had `XyzRepository xyzRepository` in both prod codebase and test it complained.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```