# Spring-Boot Application Context with ArangoDB-Repository cannot be created if using @MockBean

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mocking, arangodb

We are developing a Spring-Boot application which uses ArangoDB with the Spring-Data integration of the ArangoDB team itself (https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data).

We ran into some weird problem when we tried to develop integration tests: when we used @MockBean annotations in test classes for unrelated Spring components, the application context could not be created:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
   Error  creating bean with name 'repository': Unsatisfied dependency 
   expressed through constructor parameter 1: Ambiguous argument values for 
   parameter of type [com.arangodb.springframework.core.ArangoOperations] - 
   did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
```

It seems that the mere presence of the @MockBean Annotation produces this error.

Also, Eclipse with installed Spring Tools shows the following error on the Main class:

```
No constructor with 1 argument defined in class
'com.arangodb.springframework.repository.ArangoRepositoryFactoryBean'
```

This error message seems to be true as there only is a two-argument constructor for this factory. The tests without @MockBean do run successfully, regardless.

**Example**

We stripped out project down to a minimal example which you can find on GitHub: https://github.com/mark--/arango-mockbean-error

The relevant code is in the single test class DAOTest. If the @MockBean annotation is present the error from above occurs, if it is removed the application context is created.

**Beware**: We removed the test setup code in the example project, in particular the setup of an ArangoDB instance with docker: as a consequence the test fails also without the @MockBean annotation but only due to the missing ArangoDB.

**Update**:

The workaround from [MockBean annotation in Spring Boot test causes NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431630/mockbean-annotation-in-spring-boot-test-causes-nouniquebeandefinitionexception) (give the @MockBean a name) works for us, too, so this seems to be some Spring bug.

Comment: so what is wrong with giving the @MockBean annotation a name?

Comment: Because it is not in any way obvious that this is the "solution". As a workaround it is fine, but this is almost definitely a bug.

Comment: It is a bug yes but you have a workaround, we can't fix spring for you..

Comment: I do not expect you to fix Spring for me. I asked the question before I was aware of the bug.

Comment: well you know the solution until spring team patches I guess..

Answer (score 0):

The Arango team fixed this problem, see https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/14#issuecomment-374141173